# microsoft sql select query from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query is working in mysql but is not working in microsoft sql server management studio 2008, can someone help me out?

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.firstname,C.lastname,QC.category_name,QR.cid,QR.catid,QR.rhid 
FROM cms_question_report QR, 
cms_clients C,
cms_questioncategory QC ,
cms_reporthistory RH 
WHERE C.id=QR.cid 
AND QR.rhid=RH.id 
AND QR.catid='3' 
AND QR.catid=QC.id
```

I am getting the error: `Invalid object name cms_question_report`

Comment: Add the name of the schema (likely dbo) and make sure your editor is connecting to the database that has these tables and not the master database

Comment: Check selected database is correct or not..!!or write Use Database before this query

Comment: also, please use ANSI style joins....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.firstname,C.lastname,QC.category_name,QR.cid,QR.catid,QR.rhid 
FROM cms_question_report QR
left join cms_clients C
on C.id=QR.cid 
left join cms_questioncategory QC
on QR.catid=QC.id
and QR.catid='3'
left join cms_reporthistory RH
on QR.rhid=RH.id
```

I think this should do

Comment: This will only join on catid=3. In their example, they filter on catid=3. That's a significant difference.

Comment: he/she wanted only catid=3

Comment: But this will return all catids and only incur the join on catid = 3

Comment: Anyways, I might have a misunderstanding, they accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

specify Normally it happens when you have specific schema and you don't specify it for example:

Replace dbo. with your schema and/or type your database name

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.firstname,C.lastname,QC.category_name,QR.cid,QR.catid,QR.rhid 
FROM databasename.dbo.cms_question_report QR, 
databasename.dbo.cms_clients C,
databasename.dbo.cms_questioncategory QC ,
databasename.dbo.cms_reporthistory RH 
WHERE C.id=QR.cid 
AND QR.rhid=RH.id 
AND QR.catid='3' 
AND QR.catid=QC.id
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using other queries without including the dbo, but anyway I tried your query and I got the error: `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`

Comment: Try again "replacing databasename with the name of your database" and remove the '*'